How to ensure persistence when passing data beween pages?
I had to create an Appointment page using react native and another page that displays all the appointments a "client` has made.
However, I'm unsure how to pass data/parameters from the Appointment page to the My Appointments page and ensure that the data persists on the My Appointments page. I've already used the route.params and stuff but I'm pretty sure the data doesn't persists.
Can someone help me, please?
Appointments page:
const AgendamentoAdv = () => {
  const [agendamentos, setAgendamentos] = useState([]);
  const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false);
  const [idAgendamento, setIdAgendamento] = useState(null);
  const [nome, setNome] = useState('');
  const [prof, setProf] = useState('');
  const [obs, setObs] = useState('');
  const [data, setData] = useState(moment(new Date()).format('DD/MM/YYYY'));

  const navigation = useNavigation();

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchAgendamentos();
  }, []);

  const fetchAgendamentos = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(API_URL);
      const data = await response.json();
      setAgendamentos(data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Erro ao buscar agendamentos:", error);
    }
  };

  const salvarAgendamento = async () => {
    const agendamento = { id: idAgendamento, nome, prof, obs, data };
    const method = idAgendamento ? 'PUT' : 'POST';
    const url = idAgendamento ? `${API_URL}/${idAgendamento}` : API_URL;

    try {
      const response = await fetch(url, {
        method,
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        body: JSON.stringify(agendamento),
      });

      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error('Erro ao salvar agendamento');
      }

      fetchAgendamentos();
      fecharModal();
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Erro ao salvar agendamento:", error);
      Alert.alert("Erro", "Ocorreu um problema ao tentar salvar o agendamento.");
    }
  };

  const abrirFormulario = (agendamento = { id: null, nome: '', prof: '', obs: '', data: moment(new Date()).format('DD/MM/YYYY') }) => {
    setIdAgendamento(agendamento.id);
    setNome(agendamento.nome);
    setProf(agendamento.prof);
    setObs(agendamento.obs);
    setData(agendamento.data);
    setModalVisible(true);
  };

  const handleDelete = async (id) => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(`${API_URL}/${id}`, { method: 'DELETE' });
      if (response.ok) {
        setAgendamentos(agendamentos.filter(agendamento => agendamento.id !== id));
      } else {
        throw new Error('Erro ao excluir agendamento');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Erro ao excluir agendamento:", error);
      Alert.alert("Erro", "Ocorreu um problema ao tentar excluir o agendamento.");
    }
  };

  const fecharModal = () => {
    setIdAgendamento(null);
    setNome('');
    setProf('');
    setObs('');
    setData(moment(new Date()).format('DD/MM/YYYY'));
    setModalVisible(false);
  };

  const renderAgendamento = ({ item }) => (
  <View style={styles.card}>
    <View style={styles.info}>
      <Text style={styles.nome}>{item.nome} - {item.prof}</Text>
      <Text style={styles.obs}>Observação: {item.obs}</Text>
      <Text style={styles.data}>Data: {item.data}</Text>
      <View style={styles.actions}>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.actionButton} onPress={() => abrirFormulario(item)}>
          <Icon name="pencil" size={20} color="#FF7F7F" />
          <Text style={styles.actionText}>Editar</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.actionButton} onPress={() => handleDelete(item.id)}>
          <Icon name="trash-can-outline" size={20} color="#FF7F7F" />
          <Text style={styles.actionText}>Excluir</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
      <Button
            style={styles.botao}
            mode="contained"
            onPress={() => navigation.navigate('meusagendamentos', { nome: item.nome, prof: item.prof, data: item.data, obs: item.obs })}>
  Agendar
          </Button>
    </View>
  </View>
);


use redux to better state mangment OR use 'usecontex'
